# Converting hex color to RGBA and vice-versa

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

While this question has already been asked, I'm having some trouble converting a bunch of hex values into the same format matplotlib.colors.to_rgba puts out like this.

```
import matplotlib.colors

matplotlib.colors.to_rgba('#B4FBB8FF')
(0.7058823529411765, 0.984313725490196, 0.7215686274509804, 1.0)
```

But I am trying to get the command to convert more than one at a time.

I knew this probably wasn't going to work. I only added another matplotlib.colors.to_rgba to the command just to see if it'll work, but of course it didn't.

If anyone can help with this, it'll be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just do what you're doing but in a loop?

Comment: When you say "more than one at a time" it would be useful to see what your input looks like.

Comment: My input is just matplotlib.colors.to_rgba('#B4FBB8FF') and repeat for like 254 colours, but since it's so many colours, I feel like a txt file would be better for this formatted with every colour in a column.

Comment: It's the "and repeat" part I'm having trouble with.  Without knowing how you're getting your repeating data, it's hard to make a recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, either use a loop (as @*Mark Ransom* mentionned) or use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) :

```
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgba
import random
​
hex_colors = ["#"+"".join([random.choice("0123456789ABCDEF")
                       for j in range(6)]) for i in range(5)]

rgba_colors = list(map(to_rgba, hex_colors))
```

In this example, we generate 5 random hex colors then convert those to [RGBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_model) with [`matplotlib.colors.to_rgba`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.to_rgba.html).

Output :

```
print(hex_colors)
​#['#EF00BE', '#543B4D', '#9A8522', '#63F40C', '#611E42']

print(rgba_colors)

[(0.9372549019607843, 0.0, 0.7450980392156863, 1.0),
 (0.32941176470588235, 0.23137254901960785, 0.30196078431372547, 1.0),
 (0.6039215686274509, 0.5215686274509804, 0.13333333333333333, 1.0),
 (0.38823529411764707, 0.9568627450980393, 0.047058823529411764, 1.0),
 (0.3803921568627451, 0.11764705882352941, 0.25882352941176473, 1.0)]
```

Comment: That's basically what I want but the colours I want aren't random they could be formatted like so ('#5F1F14FF', '#632014FF', '#672114FF', '#6B2214FF', '#6F2414FF', '#732514FF', '#772614FF', '#7B2713FF')

Comment: I made random colors just to show you the general logic ;). In your case, assign your tupe/list to a variable (i.e `my_colors`) and then pass it to `map` like so : `list(map(to_rgba, my_colors))`.